# Building a minimal Linux for Raspberry Pi

Tags: setup, linux

Now I got my Raspberry Pi. I am an experienced application software developer, but I've never done hardware stuff or low-level programming before. I want to build a minimal Linux, including drivers for all hardware on my Pi. For learning purpose, I don't want to install any pre-built Linux distribution on my Pi. Where should I start?

Comment: Have you done any research at all? Do you have any idea of what you would like to achieve, besides something that's minimal.

Comment: Building a minimal Linux itself on the board cannot be a goal? Does it need to be as big as say, building THE Android killer?

Comment: And I am asking how to get started, not asking someone to walk me through from start to finish. Why down vote? Beginners are not welcome?

Comment: @powerboy I've played around with BuildRoot. It's a project to build minimal Linux environments for embedded systems. I'm still not sure if it's a good match for the RPi or not since the RPi is both an embedded system and a regular computer. For example, a BuildRoot system doesn't have a package system like APT on Debian. I've used this customized BuildRoot configuration, customized for Qt5: https://github.com/nezticle/RaspberryPi-BuildRoot

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You basically have three levels to choose your starting point from:

1. Satisfy for something already available and concentrate on doing the hardware stuff. In this case I recommend you [Adafruit Occidentalis](http://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-raspberry-pi-educational-linux-distro/overview), a debian based distribution aimed for people interested in HW-modding of the RPi.
2. Start creating a new distribution. Here's a generic link to get started from: http://www.tuxradar.com/content/how-build-your-own-linux-distro
3. Create a totally custom Operating System, but then there is no reason to call it Linux. Here's a link for on on-line course: http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/freshers/raspberrypi/tutorials/os/

Comment: +1 on #3 there. I'm going through it now and its a good insight into ARM assembly and some basic OS operations.

Comment: I am doing the same thing! Nice beginner tutorial!